# How to remove a div containing ad code after an ad click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, adsense

This is an online editor:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

This ad code will work on that w3 site because it's their pub code:

```
    <div id="ad">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1993393738408076"
    data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </div>
```

Can we hide/remove adsense ad after a single click, so that people can't click multiple times until page gets refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look this answer from google.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/39L0eOvw0dY/FKZIeYbAZncJ